# How to run a Jenkins Pipeline Stage on a single agent?

Tags: jenkins

I have a stage of my pipeline that launches two Docker containers - one Localstack (https://github.com/localstack/localstack) and one python:3.6 for testing AWS integrations. My issue is that Jenkins is splitting up the stage so that one Docker container is running on one agent and the other container is running on another agent. The stage relies on the ability of these two containers to talk to each other. This is not possible with them running on separate agents.

Here is my test stage:

```
stage("Test") {
  agent any

  steps {
    script {
      withDockerNetwork{ n ->
        docker.image('localstack/localstack').withRun("--network ${n} --env-file localstack.env") { c ->
          docker.image('python:3.6').inside("""
            --user 0
            --network ${n}
            --mount type=bind,source=${env.WORKSPACE}/lambda,target=/work \
            -w /tmp
          """) {
            sh "bash /work/test.sh"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I force this stage to be run entirely on a single agent?

Comment: If it's possible for you to work with Declarative Pipeline instead of Scripted, `reuseNode` option gives you exactly that.

Comment: If you want to use one specific node you could just explicitly use it instead of the `agent any` but if you want just any one node shared for both containers you can use the option @hilsenrat hinted at, since it seems like you are using declarative pipelines. You can find the documentation here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent